# Is it possible to inject one config file to another config?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, app-config, configuration-files

I just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34106651/5644807) answer and I started wondering. Let's say, I have multi-project solution (with many executable clients). Every client would have App.config as normal, but without WCF part. Without `system.serviceModel` section.

In separate Class Library I would have App.config where I would put `system.serviceModel` section ONLY. So when I run client with that Class Library as reference, VS will somehow inject config from Class Library into Client (let's say WinForms).

That way, I will separate WCF stuff completely. WinForms Client will only have reference to Library Class and that's it.

So, is it possible to inject one config file to another config file?

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569117/net-config-files-configsource-outside-the-application-directory-folder) is one of your options as system.Servicemodel doesn't support [configSource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940004/asp-net-web-config-configsource-vs-file-attributes)